# Responsive table column by column

Tags: html, responsive

I've build a responsive table like in this [example](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php) . It works pretty well, but I do not want a break for all elements, I want to break the table by column. Means more like that on full view:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  |    (TH)
+----+----+----+----+
| a  | b  | c  | d  |    (TR/TD)
+----+----+----+----+
| e  | f  | g  | h  |     (TR/TD)
+----+----+----+----+
```

And on 600 pixel with:

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | 
+----+----+----+
| a  | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+
| D     d      |
+----+----+----+
| e  | f  | g  |
+----+----+----+
| D     h      |
+----+----+----+
```

On 400px I switch automatically to this card view:

```
+--------------+
| A     a      |
+--------------+
| B     b      |
+--------------+
| C     c      |
+--------------+
| D     d      |
+--------------+
+--------------+
| A     e      |
+--------------+
| B     f      |
+--------------+
| C     g      |
+--------------+
| D     h      |
+--------------+
```

Is there a way to do this with meta tags and CSS?

Comment: Why do you have "D" twice in the 600px example?

Comment: It's the header. I have a data-field for each td, which includes the name of the header. This is shown in the example above. For every row, I create a card view (see edit), if the browser window is smaller then 400px (mobile view).